# Не пойму как работает column-count

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Почему не выводится в 3 колонки как задано в column-count?

```css
.photo-gallery {
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: .3em;
}

.photo-item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 .3em;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="photo-gallery">

  <div class="photo-item">
    <a href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/600/400" alt="image"></a>
  </div>

  <div class="photo-item">
    <a href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/600/400" alt="image"></a>
  </div>

  <div class="photo-item">
    <a href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/600/400" alt="image"></a>
  </div>

  <div class="photo-item">
    <a href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/600/400" alt="image"></a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Добавь еще один блок, будет по 3

Comment: Да, но нужно чтобы любое количество фото располагались равномерно. Вот тут то и проблема, нормально распределяется только 5 и более объектов.

Comment: Вариант с `flexbox` не рассматриваете?

Comment: Да, скорее всего придется искать другой метод решения задачи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> CSS3 спецификация Колонки требует, что высота колонки должна быть выровнена: т.е., браузер автоматически устанавливает максимальную высоту колоноки, для того чтобы высота содержимого в каждой колонки была приблизительно одинаковая. 
>   [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multi-column_layouts)

Так как контента у вас для трех колонок по мнению браузера недостаточно, то и три колонки он не создаёт.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо!

Comment: @СергейМиронов если это отвечает на ваш вопрос, то примите ответ.